# How to increase , precision-recall value in your Deep learning model

Tags: deep-learning, anomaly-detection, precision-recall-curve

I am getting good accuracy metrics around 80 with precision =66, recall =37, F1 =47. How can I improve precision, and recall metrics in anomaly detection scenarios.. any suggestions?

Comment: If your F1 is 47 and your accuracy is 80, then you have considerable class imbalance, and should not be using the accuracy score at all - it is too much influenced by the size of the majority class.

Answer (score 0):

I think this ways will help you :

1. Feature engineering
2. Use ensemble methods
3. Adjusting thresholds
4. Collect more data
5. Use data augmentation and oversampling
6. Use a different algorithm, such as autoencoders or one-class SVM
7. Tune the hyperparameters

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).